# Telegram bot start message

Tags: c#, .net, telegram, telegram-bot

How can I make my bot to show a default message, when entering chat with it?
What I mean, is smth like BotFather's bot description
[image: I mean this "What can this bot do" part]

Not necessarily like this, it can be kind of message, but it should appear when the user is entering the chat, not after user send a first message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Bot Father menu like:

1. Use `/mybots`
2. Choose the bot you want to edit
3. Click ***Edit Description***
4. Send the description you want for your bot

[image: Bot father edit description photo]